# Can I learn Lockpickin' after I leave the farm?

Tags: west-of-loathing

When I chose which skill to learn at the start of the game, I chose Dickerin' since it seemed like it was going to be pretty useful. However, I'm running in to a lot more locked objects than I am people who I can Dicker with, and I'd like to learn Lockpickin'. Is there any way for me to learn this skill after I leave the farm?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes, you can learn the Lockpickin' from a skillbook sold by vendors. I've seen this book sold by the Dirtwater mercantile as well as by Wanderin' Sally.

The vendors' inventory seems to be randomized, so they don't always carry it, but eventually it will be there.